# Table Data Binding not working in angular 9

Tags: html, angular, angular9

How to bind master and detail data in angular 9 during saving the form.

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you could add more details to your question. Like the code, you tried or the error you are getting. You can also share a minimal reproducible example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/). Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get tips on improving your chances of getting an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have found solution. Thank you for your reply

Comment: That's great. It will be good if you share your solution as an answer to this question and accept it to help others.

Comment: Ok i will update answer for this question after 1-2 days please review it. @GopalMishra